# MYSQLi Update Query Failing - Works in PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

** Solved

The following query works fine when I run it in phpmydmin, but it always fails when I run it via mysqli query.

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `owner` SET `country-translate`= 'United States' WHERE `country` IS NULL AND `state` IS NOT NULL") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

It does not throw any errors, I have other update queries working, but this seems to be the only one looking for null values. Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: On your table structures, are you allowing null values?  I'm not sure if this would be the issues, your questions slightly vague given the lack of any errors which makes me think it's running fine, just not finding the values as you don't have any countries that are actually null.

Comment: All values set to null if not provided, even more mysterious as to why it's failing :(

Comment: Maybe is a permission issue? Are you using the same user for PhpMyAdmin and your php code?

Comment: I figured it out! The code was written months ago and the issue was very obscure. Short story, initial data dump - not all countries are null (some are some are not). So even though the table is set to nullable values for all columns, they are not all null... not till later when another query cleans it all up to make it consistent. That's where I screwed up. Gotta love revisiting code you wrote forever ago..